# How to store data via relationship in constructor of SQLAlchemy model?

Tags: python, python-2.7, constructor, sqlalchemy, one-to-many

How to add objects in the constructor with relationship? The id is not yet ready when constructor is evaluated. In simpler cases it is possible to just provide a list, calculated beforehand. In the example below I tried to say there is a `complex_cls_method`, in a way it is more like black box.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

DB_URL = "mysql://user:password@localhost/exampledb?charset=utf8"

engine = create_engine(DB_URL, encoding='utf-8', convert_unicode=True, pool_recycle=3600, pool_size=10)
session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)()

Model = declarative_base()


class User(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    simple = Column(String(255))
    main_address = Column(String(255))
    addresses = relationship("Address",
                             cascade="all, delete-orphan")

    def __init__(self, addresses, simple):
        self.simple = simple
        self.main_address = addresses[0]
        return  # because the following does not work
        self.addresses = Address.complex_cls_method(
            user_id_=self.id,  # <-- this does not work of course
            key_="address",
            value_=addresses
        )


class Address(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    keyword = Column(String(255))
    value = Column(String(255))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('address.id'), nullable=True)

    @classmethod
    def complex_cls_method(cls, user_id_, key_, value_):
        main = Address(keyword=key_, value="", user_id=user_id_, parent_id=None)
        session.add_all([main])
        session.flush()
        addrs = [Address(keyword=key_, value=item, user_id=user_id_, parent_id=main.id) for item in value_]
        session.add_all(addrs)
        return [main] + addrs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Model.metadata.create_all(engine)
    user = User([u"address1", u"address2"], "simple")
    session.add(user)
    session.flush()

    # as it can't be done in constructor, these additional statements needed 

    user.addresses = Address.complex_cls_method(
        user_id_=user.id,
        key_="address",
        value_=[u"address1", u"address2"]
    )
    session.commit()
```

The question is, is there syntactically elegant (and technically sound) way to do this with User's constructor, or is it safer to just call a separate method of User class after session.flush to add desired objects to relationships (as in the example code)?

Giving up on constructor altogether is still possible, but less desirable option as resulting signature change would require significant refactorings.

Comment: "so the only ways to add something to it's 1-to-many relationships is to flush first, then ..." is somewhat incorrect. SQLA can handle persisting complex object graphs just fine (usually) – that's one of its selling points. You've omitted too much information from your post. For example: what's `User.main_address` like? You've displayed the self referential foreign key in Address, but not how you're using it etc. Please provide a [mcve], where you display in a minimal fashion what you're actually trying to do, instead of describing it.

Comment: Now I have (non) working example and simpler explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually flushing and setting ids etc. you could let SQLAlchemy handle persisting your object graph. You'll just need one more [adjacency list relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html) in `Address` and you're all set:

```
class User(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    simple = Column(String(255))
    main_address = Column(String(255))
    addresses = relationship("Address",
                             cascade="all, delete-orphan")

    def __init__(self, addresses, simple):
        self.simple = simple
        self.main_address = addresses[0]
        self.addresses = Address.complex_cls_method(
            key="address",
            values=addresses
        )


class Address(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    keyword = Column(String(255))
    value = Column(String(255))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('address.id'), nullable=True)
    # For handling parent/child relationships in factory method
    parent = relationship("Address", remote_side=[id])

    @classmethod
    def complex_cls_method(cls, key, values):
        main = cls(keyword=key, value="")
        addrs = [cls(keyword=key, value=item, parent=main) for item in values]
        return [main] + addrs    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    user = User([u"address1", u"address2"], "simple")
    session.add(user)
    session.commit()
    print(user.addresses)
```

Note the absence of manual flushes etc. SQLAlchemy automatically figures out the required order of insertions based on the object relationships, so that dependencies between rows can be honoured. This is a part of the [Unit of Work](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html) pattern.

Comment: Works like magic, thanks! I am especially glad new code has less parameters than old.

Comment: I don't totally understand. Can I get some help? Why is there a relationship between Address and Address? What is the "parent/child" relationship? @Ilja If you can direct me to a resource you found helpful, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks. EDIT - the link you posted above (SQLAlchemy docs) is great. Thanks and nevermind.

Comment: EDIT2 - still a bit unsure of whether this is the right pattern for this question.

Comment: @ZachSiegel The `Address` [adjacency list](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html) is irrelevant to this answer mostly, and you'd have to ask the OP as to why it exists. The point of this answer is to demonstrate that SQLAlchemy can figure out dependencies between pending instances based on ORM relationships and order inserts so that no manual flushes are needed for fetching primary key values for populating foreign keys – which is what the OP was asking about: "The id is not yet ready when constructor is evaluated."

Comment: @ZachSiegel Perhaps you should ask a question of your own? It is unclear what you need help with. Also note that comments are not meant for prolonged discussions or asking new questions (of course it's fine to ask for additional details about a question or an answer).